# how to use "in" condition with many text define in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, text, phpmyadmin

i want to get correct result from my condition, here is my condition

this is my database

[image: database]

and here is my code :

my define text

```
#define
country = ('america','indonesia', 'england', 'france')
city = ('new york', 'jakarta', 'london', 'paris')

c1="Country"
c2="City"
c3="<blank>"
```

and condition ("text" here is passing from select database, ofc using looping - for)

```
if str(text) in str(country) :
        stat=c1
    elif str(text) in str(city) :
        stat=c2
    else :
        stat=c3
```

and i got wrong result for the condition, like this
[image: result]

any solution to make this code work ? it work when just contain 1 text when using "in", but this case define so many text condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you need.

```
text = "i was born in paris"
country = ('america','indonesia', 'england', 'france')
city = ('new york', 'jakarta', 'london', 'paris')

def check(text):
    for i in country:
        if i in text.lower():
            return "Country"
    for i in city:
        if i in text.lower():
            return "City"
    return "<blank>"

print(check(text))
print(check("I dnt like vacation in america"))
```

**Output:**

```
City
Country
```

Comment: thanks sir, it is really help. it work also with text from database. @Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

You could be better off using dictionaries. I assume that text is a list:

```
dict1 = {
    "countries" : ['america','indonesia', 'england', 'france'],
    "city" : ['new york', 'jakarta', 'london', 'paris']
}

for x in text:
    for y in dict1['countries']:
        if y in x:
            print 'country: ' + x
    for z in dict1['city']:
        if z in x:
            print 'city: ' + x
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, it works with little modification. nearly same with sir rakesh answer, in fact both of ur answer has same method, thanks sir @Rthomas529

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check what you are testing.

```
>>> country = ('america','indonesia', 'england', 'france')
>>> city = ('new york', 'jakarta', 'london', 'paris')
>>>
>>> c1="Country"
>>> c2="City"
>>> c3="<blank>"
```

Same as your setup. So, you are testing for the presence of a substring.

```
>>> str(country)
"('america', 'indonesia', 'england', 'france')"
```

Let's see if we can find a country.

```
>>> 'america' in str(country)
True
```

Yes! Unfortunately a simple string test such as the one above, besides involving an unnecessary conversion of the list to a string, also finds things that aren't countries.

```
>>> "ca', 'in" in str(country)
True
```

The `in` test for strings is true if the string to the right contains the substring on the left. The `in` test for lists is different, however, and is true when the tested list contains the value on the left as an element.

```
>>> 'america' in country
True
```

Nice! Have got got rid of the "weird other matches" bug?

```
>>> "ca', 'in" in country
False
```

It would appear so. However, using the list inclusion test you need to check *every word* in the input string rather than the whole string.

```
>>> "I don't like to vacation in america" in country
False
```

The above is similar to what you are doing now, but testing list elements rather than the list as a string. This expression generates a list of words in the input.

```
>>> [word for word in "I don't like to vacation in america".split()]
['I', "don't", 'like', 'to', 'vacation', 'in', 'america']
```

Note that you may have to be more careful than I have been in splitting the input. In the example above, `"america, steve"` when split would give `['america,', 'steve']` and neither word would match.

The `any` function iterates over a sequence of expressions, returning `True` at the first true member of the sequence (and `False` if no such element is found). (Here I use a generator expression instead of a list, but the same iterable sequence is generated).

```
>>> any(word in country for word in "I don't like to vacation in america".split())
True
```

For extra marks (and this is left as an exercise for the reader) you could write
a function that takes two arguments, a sentence and a list of possible matches,
and returns True if any of the words in the sentence are present in the list. Then you could use two different calls to that function to handle the countries and the
cities.

You could speed things up somewhat by using sets rather than lists, but the principles are the same.

Comment: actually, i also using text mining in my real project. ofc there is tokenization which split text from database. and it still didn't work sir. but thanks for ur response, i appreciate, thanks